# delete line where no second field available

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have file in ldif format example given below

```
cn: DINAKAR PERI
deptcode: DBS
sn: PERI
givenName: DINAKAR
roomNo: B 208
officePhone:
Resphone:
mail: dinakar@tifr.res.in
officePhone:
mobile:
```

I want to delete the line where no second field available.

output:

```
cn: DINAKAR PERI
deptcode: DBS
sn: PERI
givenName: DINAKAR
roomNo: B 208
mail: dinakar@tifr.res.in
```

I tried with this command

```
awk 'NF > 1' test.ldif >test1.ldif
```

it worked well but does not fulfill my requirement.

Thanks
sagar

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
awk 'NF > 1' test.ldif > tmp && mv tmp test.ldif
```

You can not write to the file you are reading. Use the `tmp` file option
The `&&` would be run if output of `awk` is `ok`

`sed` has the `-i` option to do in place edit, `awk` does not.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, `sed` might be easier because it will change-in-place all by itself:

```
sed -i -n '/[[:space:]][[:alnum:]]/p' test.ldif
```

The `-i` option tells `sed` to change the file, as you are trying to do, *in place*.  The `-n` option tells `sed` not to print lines unless we ask it to.  The command `/[[:space:]][[:alnum:]]/p` to tells `sed` to look for lines that have a space in them followed by a character and print those lines.  Thus, the only lines that end up in the final file are those which have a second field.

Comment: This fails if there are space after the word  like `Resphone:  `, `awk` ignore this.  You can also join the option and write `sed -in '...`

Comment: @Jotne  Thanks. I updated the code to handle that the case of trailing whitespace.  _"You can also join the option and write sed -in"_:  No.  Joining it that way results in the creation of a backup file with suffix 'n' among other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am newer to shell scripting and having less knowledge but I did it with below commands

inside the file

```
:%s/.*: *$/dd/gc -- this replace my all blank lines with dd
```

y to all

on shell

```
#sed '/^dd/d' test.ldif > test1.ldif -- this will remove all line begining with dd
```

Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/\S\+/&/2;t;d' file
```

If you cannot replace a second non-whitespace field by its self, delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed '/:[ \t]*$/d' test.ldif >test1.ldif
```

and if your sed supports `-i` option, and you can directly update it

```
sed -i '/:[ \t]*$/d' test.ldif
```